# Extra garbage values added when posting JSON data using cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to create an API using cURL & JSON.
Now In my first PHP file I am sending data as JSON data, Like below:

```
public function index()
{
    $url = 'http://172.24.130.50/testbiz/server/login';

    $field_string = "{“Request”: “Login”, “Username”: anonymous, “APIAccessKey”: “AW342FFGRTR56RTH”, “GMT-Timestamp”: “1489670000”}";
    $json =  json_encode($field_string);
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);



    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);


    echo "<pre>".$result."</pre>";

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

But on my SERVER where I get this request when I show (using `var_export()`) the values:

```
public function login()
{

    $client_data = $this->input->post();


    var_export($client_data);

}
```

**Error:**

> array ( '"{\u201cRequest\u201d:*\u201cLogin\u201d,*\u201cUsername\u201d:*\u201cBIZRTC\u201d,*\u201cAPIAccessKey\u201d:*\u201cAW342FFGRTR56RTH\u201d,*\u201cGMT-Timestamp\u201d:_\u201c1489670000\u201d}"' => '', 0 => '', )

Even if I decode it there I still get `\u`. Also I dont understand how are these values appended  : at starting : `'"{\\u201c`  and this `\\u201d}"' => '', 0 => '',` at the back.

What are these values?

How do I decode this JSON?

Am I Posting right data to Server?

**Updated code**

Client.php

```
public function index()
{
    $url = 'http://172.24.130.50/testbiz/server/login';


    $field_string = array("reqest"=>"login", "user_name"=> "anonymous", "API_AccessKey"=> "AW342FFGRTR56RTH", "GMT_Timestamp"=> "1489670000");
    $json =  json_encode($field_string);

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);


    echo "<pre>".$result."</pre>";

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Server.php

```
public function login()
{


    var_export($_POST);



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are storing json string in variable then you don't need the `json_encode()` because it is used to convert array to json string.

```
    $field_string = '{“Request”: “Login”, “Username”: anonymous, “APIAccessKey”: “AW342FFGRTR56RTH”, “GMT-Timestamp”: “1489670000”}';
        $json =  $field_string;
//open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))                                                                       
);
```

Comment: i get this  : `array ( '{“Request”:_“Login”,_“Username”:_anonymous,_“APIAccessKey”:_“AW342FFGRTR56RTH”,_“GMT-Timestamp”:_“1489670000”}' => '', 0 => '', )`

Comment: Yes I dont know how to handle the `' => '', 0 => '', `

Comment: How do i print that on other side ? how it shows empty array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138627/discussion-between-rajan-and-varun-malhotra).

Comment: Hey I am getting this : `{"reqest":"login","user_name":"anonymous","API_AccessKey":"AW342FFGRTR56RTH","GMT_Timestamp":"1489670000"}`

Comment: How do i process this from `$_POST`

Comment: now simply put this string in variable and put that variable in json_decode();

like This

$newvar = json_decode($variable);

and access these like this

echo $newvar->reqest;

it will return "login";

Comment: See i did this  : `$raw_json = json_decode($_POST);
echo $raw_json;`

Comment: I get this error : `<p>Message:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given</p>`

Comment: how did you print the last string this one   {"reqest":"login","user_name":"anonymous","API_AccessKey":"A‌​W342FFGRTR56RTH","GM‌​T_Timestamp":"148967‌​0000"}

Comment: I did var_dump $_POST

Comment: and this was the actual content i got `C:\wamp\www\testbiz\application\controllers\Server.php:16:
array (size=2)
  '{"reqest":"login","user_name":"anonymous","API_AccessKey":"AW342FFGRTR56RTH","GMT_Timestamp":"1489670000"}' => string '' (length=0)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
1`

Comment: check what is printing on print_r($_POST);

Comment: in PRINT_R its print this : `Array ( [{"reqest":"login","user_name":"anonymous","API_AccessKey":"AW342FFGRTR56RTH","GMT_Timestamp":"1489670000"}] => [0] => ) `

Comment: how do i get the single elements

Comment: ok now do this $d = array_keys($_POST); $da = json_decode($d[0]); echo $da->reqest; it suppose to be return 'login'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give array in `json_encode`, Instead of string.

**Replace:**

```
 $field_string = "{“Request”: “Login”, “Username”: anonymous, “APIAccessKey”: “AW342FFGRTR56RTH”, “GMT-Timestamp”: “1489670000”}";
    $json =  json_encode($field_string);
```

**To:**

```
$field_string= '{
   "Request": "Login",
   "Username": "anonymous",
   "APIAccessKey": "AW342FFGRTR56RTH",
   "GMT-Timestamp": "1489670000"
}';
```

**Problems in code:**

1. Incorrect `json`.
2. Invalid quotes(`”`) in `json`.
3. Passing string in `json_encode`.

Comment: I am getting this as response `'"{\\r\\n___\\"Request\\":_\\"Login\\",\\r\\n___\\"Username\\":_\\"anonymous\\",\\r\\n___\\"APIAccessKey\\":_\\"AW342FFGRTR56RTH\\",\\r\\n___\\"GMT-Timestamp\\":_\\"1489670000\\"\\r\\n}"' => '', 0 => '', )`

Comment: I have corrected all the mistakes in your code.. Might the api on which you are requesting is not working properly. try to use this `{"Request": "Login", "Username": "anonymous", "APIAccessKey": "AW342FFGRTR56RTH", "GMT-Timestamp": "1489670000"}` Json. I am providing you the complete curl request try to check with that also on terminal

Comment: @ sahil now i get this `'{""{\\"Request\\":_\\"Login\\",_\\"Username\\":_\\"anonymous\\",_\\"APIAccessKey\\":_\\"AW342FFGRTR56RTH\\",_\\"GMT-Timestamp\\":_\\"1489670000\\"}"":"","0":""}'` and when i check in json validator it shows invalid

Comment: Also i want to know how to get rid of these `\` at a time, i tried using stripslashes but it does not remove all the slash

Comment: i want to ask one thing are doing `json_encode` again ? you dont need to do `json_encode` because this `{"Request": "Login", "Username": "anonymous", "APIAccessKey": "AW342FFGRTR56RTH", "GMT-Timestamp": "1489670000"}` is already a json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138593/discussion-between-rajan-and-sahil-gulati).

Answer (score 1):

it is because of below line

```
$field_string = "{“Request”: “Login”, “Username”: anonymous, “APIAccessKey”: “AW342FFGRTR56RTH”, “GMT-Timestamp”: “1489670000”}";
    $json =  json_encode($field_string);
```

suppose to be like this

```
$field_string = array("reqest"=>"login", "user_name"=> "anonymous", "API_AccessKey"=> "AW342FFGRTR56RTH", "GMT_Timestamp"=> "1489670000");
    $json =  json_encode($field_string);
```

Comment: It shows an error : Message: Use of undefined constant “Request” - assumed '“Request”'

Comment: its because the Request is a predefined constant use something else on place of Request

Comment: it says for all request, username codeditor  does show me as string it shows as constant

Comment: No i think the double quotes are wrong somewhere, because in sublime text it shows me constant instead of string

Comment: no the qotes will remian same please show me the error string you got

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138594/discussion-between-rajan-and-varun-malhotra).

Comment: hey there is problem, the input u gave does not have JSON its plain array

Comment: bro we are converting it to json while assigning to variable $json and when you recive this string on other side and put it in to json_decode it will return you the classobject type array.

Comment: but when i var_dump $_POST on server side I get array directly instead of jSOn objects

Comment: I am getting this  : `array ( 'reqest' => 'login', 'user_name' => 'anonymous', 'API_AccessKey' => 'AW342FFGRTR56RTH', 'GMT_Timestamp' => '1489670000', )` should i not get JSON data on server

Comment: no because curl request converts the json to array and if you want that in json then simply put that array in json_encode() and you are good to go

Comment: No I juist checked before sending the data if i `var_dump($field_strings)` I get : `array (size=4)
  'reqest' => string 'login' (length=5)
  'user_name' => string 'anonymous' (length=9)
  'API_AccessKey' => string 'AW342FFGRTR56RTH' (length=16)
  'GMT_Timestamp' => string '1489670000' (length=10)`

Comment: yes bro just put that in json_encode function like this $newjson = json_encode($yourarray); and vardump $newjson.

Comment: Okay there was a little mistake i solved it but when i `var_dump($_POST)` on server side i get invalid json ? like this : `array ( '{"reqest":"login","user_name":"anonymous","API_AccessKey":"AW342FFGRTR56RTH","GMT_Timestamp":"1489670000"}' => '', 0 => '', )`

Comment: why is there an extra zero  and => at the back ?

Comment: Yes i have added the code below the old question code please check

Comment: i have entered another answer please check.

Comment: ok now do this

$d = array_keys($_POST);

$da = json_decode($d[0]);

echo $da->reqest;

it suppose to be return 'login'.